# How vagrantfile use dowloaded vagrant box

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

After I download centos6.6 vagrant box from official site of vagrant . but how to use them ,in the Vagrantfile ?

Answer (score 2):

I get it aha,

use the 
on windows :

```
config.vm.box_url = "file:///path-to-vbox/package.box"
```

on linux :

```
config.vm.box_url = "/path-to-vbox/package.box"
```

After I used this way , but the best way is :

```
vagrant box add titile pasth-to-vbox
```

Comment: This works but doesn't had the box in the vagrant box registry

Answer (score 1):

To add a box you have downloaded in vagrant use this command :

```
vagrant box add {title} {url or path to the .box}
```

You can list the box you installed with this command:

```
vagrant box list
# example output :
hashicorp/precise32   (virtualbox, 1.0.0) 
mitchellh/boot2docker (virtualbox, 1.2.0)
```

To use a box, the simpliest way is to put this parameter in your `Vagrantfile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "mitchellh/boot2docker"
end
```

Then in this folder run the command :

```
vagrant up
```